# Post Sender Robot in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to create a program which sends post automatically to my website
Here is the class

```
using ershaco_panel.Enums;
using ershaco_panel.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ershaco_panel.Classes
{
    public class WebSite : IService
    {
        public WebSite(string username, string password)
        {
            Step = Steps.Login;
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
            RunBrowserThread();
        }

        public WebBrowser Browser
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Services ServiceType
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Steps Step
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Step == Steps.Login)
            {
                var browser = sender as WebBrowser;
                var username = browser.Document.GetElementById("uid");
                var password = browser.Document.GetElementById("pwd");
                username.SetAttribute("Value", Username);
                password.SetAttribute("Value", Password);
                Console.WriteLine("Robot Navigated to {0} Form Count : {1}", e.Url, browser.Document.Forms.Count.ToString());
                browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[0].InvokeMember("Submit");                
                Step = Steps.Dashboard;
            }
        }

        public void RunBrowserThread()
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() => {
                Browser = new WebBrowser();
                Browser.DocumentCompleted += BrowserDocumentCompleted;
                Browser.Navigate("http://www.myurl.com");
                Application.Run();
            });            
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        public void SendPost(string content)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

as you see I manage my WebBrowser  item async with DocumentComplete. but as you know in C# WebBrowser object runs activeX so it should implement in  another thread with `STA` ApatmentState.
I have a flag called 'Step' which shows Browser current step. now in SendPost method I want to change web browser url and navigate to it, should I use another thread for it? I got cofused how to implement SendPost method.
Thank you for your response

Comment: Why not just use HttpClient or WebClient instead of trying to do it through the browser? Why are you calling `Application.Run` in the thread code?

Comment: I have some parameter in my website which value is dynamic, but if you show me your solution I will thank you @RonBeyer